# COPY - PASTE usign nightwatchjs selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriver, functional-testing, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatchjs for testing purpose (http://nightwatchjs.org/).
In a page I need to simulate COPY and PASTE action. 
While copying it's not a problem, pasting it is because I can not stick with an implementation. For example in Windows I can do:

```
browser.keys([browser.Keys.CONTROL, "v"])
```

But sometimes I use MAC and it doesn't work because I have to use COMMAND instead of CONTROL and the following code doesn't work:

```
browser.keys([browser.Keys.COMMAND, "v"])
```

So I'm trying to use something that simulate the right click of the user and the selection of the Paste option from the contextual menu. I can open the contextual menu with

```
client.mouseButtonClick('right');
```

But

**How can I select the "Paste" option from the contextual menù in nightwatchjs?**

Comment: why are you testing browser copy/paste?  you can get/set text in elements without copy/paste.

Comment: Why not detect the OS and use CONTROL vs COMMAND based on the OS being used?

Comment: BTW, you can't reliably select any option from a context menu because it's browser specific behavior and Selenium can't see the contents of the context menu. You could count 4 down or whatever but if the user has some add-in installed or the ordering or count of items in the context menu changes, your script will fail and it will likely be hard to debug.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I'm testing a copy/paste functionality between two section: copy something with a button COPY that, in javascript, copy stuff into the clipboard, then I need to paste what is copied into a text input field. That's why I need it.

Comment: @JeffC unfortunatly the COMMAND + v doesn't work on MAC, there is a bug for this... but even if sounded a reasonable solution, it doesn't work. I get your point about "right click" but as far as I understood, there is a way to do something like: RIGHT CLICK, hit P (upper case) --> you have the "paste" functionality